# Calendar API's for iOS swift

Tags: swift, calendar

Im looking for an API which returns dates from today to a year from today , I'm pretty sure that there are many , but I'm not able to find one for iOS swift. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSDate {
    func xYears(x:Int)       -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitYear,        value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xQuarters(x:Int)    -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitQuarter,     value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xMonths(x:Int)      -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMonth,       value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xWeeks(x:Int)       -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear,  value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xDays(x:Int)        -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay,         value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xHours(x:Int)       -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour,        value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xMinutes(x:Int)     -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute,      value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xSeconds(x:Int)     -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitSecond,      value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
    func xNanoseconds(x:Int) -> NSDate { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitNanosecond,  value: x, toDate: self, options: nil)! }
}

NSDate().xYears(2)  // "Jan 5, 2017, 8:03 PM"
NSDate().xMonths(2) // "Mar 5, 2015, 8:03 PM"
NSDate().xDays(2)   // "Jan 7, 2015, 8:03 PM"
```

Comment: I'm a rookie developer and I don't understand how to use in in a UICollectionViewCell , could you just post some sample code

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        println(NSDate.xDays(indexPath.row) as NSString)
        var cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("dateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DateCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

Comment: I Added your code and when I try try to print the days inside cellForItemAtIndexPath it throws an error ""NSNumber is not a subtype of NSDate

Comment: NSDate().xDays(...) if you want it to count from today. Btw it returns a Date object